# Webform only reads headers from a group Excel Files due to the Tab Name

Tags: c#, excel, webforms

I am building an app to read measurement data (saved as .xls files on our network) from comparators throughout our facility via a Webform. When I query this group of files I only retrieve the headers. My code (pretty standard) will read any other Excel file I can find. I tried to remove a file from the network and save it locally, as well as rename and save it from office 2016. Note - these are .xls files and I can't change that.

** - I just discovered that there are named ranges with the same name as the file. The results I am getting are just the values in the named range and not the data from the workbook.
Here is an example of how they are named (autogenerated) "R87_1RCR0009654S_COIN"
If I rename or remove the named range this works fine.

Is there a way I can change my select statement to read these?

Here is a code sample, not sure there if there is a change I can make here to read these files.

```
private string Excel03ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'";
private string Excel07ConString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'";

                    string conStr, sheetName;
                    conStr = string.Format(Excel03ConString, info.FullName, "YES");
                    string fullPathToExcel = info.FullName;                    

                    //Get the name of the First Sheet.
                    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
                    {
                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                        {
                            cmd.Connection = con;
                            con.Open();
                            DataTable dtExcelSchema = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                            sheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
                            con.Close();
                        }
                    }

                    using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conStr))
                    {
                        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
                        {
                            using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter())
                            {
                                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + sheetName + "]";
                                cmd.Connection = con;
                                con.Open();
                                oda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                                oda.Fill(dt);
                                con.Close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: You may use https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML <<this as better alternative to deal with Excel files

Comment: Thanks @mjb I use ClosedXML all the time, but it won't read an .xls file.